# Serializing JSON results from curl commands

Tags: python, json, bash, curl

I have a `GET` curl command that talks to an API and returns a list of networks as seen below. I want to be able to extract this information using either BASH or Python.

```
    [
      {
        "id": "L_XXFS",
        "name": "Terrys_Pizza",
        "timeZone": "US/Central",
      },
      {
        "id": "L_52GF",
        "name": "Clean_Juice",
        "timeZone": "America/New_York",
      },
      {
        "id": "L_5999",
        "name": "JJ_Fish",
        "timeZone": "US/Central",
      }
    ]
```

What would be the best way to extract the information of each network while keeping that information grouped together (for every instance of `{}`) so that I can extract/assign variables and do work on each network?

For example, the value for Terry's Pizza `id: L_XXFS` must somehow know it's connected to Terry's Pizza, and not any other network.

I also will have a different number of networks returned by my call every time, so it can't be hardcoded.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Posting some code that you've tried helps. Otherwise the question is a bit too broad.

Comment: I would suggest using https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ if you are on the command line.

Comment: "... and do work on each network". You almost certainly want to do this in Python. Unless you can do the work *in* `jq`, the most you can realistically do in `bash` is display the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting the output from `curl` I would process the information via [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), e.g. like this:

```
curl ... | jq -r '.[]|.name+":"+.id'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'll add in that `jq` has the ability to find the length of objects in a return. I use `curl ... | jq -r '. | length'` and assign that value to `TOTAL_NETWORKS` and than iterate through the networks using `curl ... | jq -r '.['"$i"'] > networkvalues.txt` in a `for` loop. I assign the values by using `sed` on the file.